# How to convert EditText field to a DateTime in Android?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm building an application in Android with Xamarin and I have a problem..
I want to convert an EditText field string to a DateTime.
I'm using a SQLITE database.
I have this code:

```
btnSave.Click += (object IntentSender, EventArgs e) => {

                ConcertDB cdb = new ConcertenDB();
                Concert dataInput = new Concerten();

                dataInput.Date= Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
                cdb.insertUpdateData(dataInput);
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is basic C# - it's not platform specific

```
// assuming dt is the EditText field
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dt.Text);
```

Parse() will throw an exception if it can't handle the input.  You can also use TryParse(), which will not throw an exception

```
DateTime date = null;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dt.Text, out date) {
  // if true, you know the parse succeeded
}
```

Comment: Also consider TryParse if you don't trust the input (you really shouldn't trust EditBox) or Convert.ToString()